# c# How can I create a collection of custom objects without going through each field

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have created a class called `DataResponse` that has more than 40 public fields.  The class `DataResponse` has the same number of fields and type as what's in my database `DataRepoes` (let's assume that).

Is there a way at all to do something like linq below where I create list of objects and automatically the fields are assigned to `DataResponse` from what's in the DB?  Otherwise I have to spell out each and every those 40 fields and assign them manually when I new up DataResponse class.  Thanks

```
List<Classes.DataResponse> res = (from rx in con.DataRepoes
  where iaccess.Contains(rx.STOREID)
  select new Classes.DataResponse).ToList<Classes.DataResponse>();
```

Comment: Maybe [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the flexibility provided by AutoMapper or don't want using a third party library, you can use the following simplified custom extension method:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TResult> SelectTo<TResult>(this IQueryable source)
    {
        var sourceType = source.ElementType;
        var resultType = typeof(TResult);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "x");
        var bindings =
            from rm in resultType.GetProperties().Concat<MemberInfo>(resultType.GetFields())
            join sm in sourceType.GetProperties().Concat<MemberInfo>(sourceType.GetFields())
                on rm.Name equals sm.Name
            select Expression.Bind(rm, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, sm));
        var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(resultType), bindings);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Select", new[] { sourceType, resultType },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(body, parameter))));
    }
}
```

It will try to select all the properties/fields that match by name. Will fail if matched property/field types differ.

Sample usage:

*Method syntax*

```
var res = con.DataRepoes
    .Where(rx => iaccess.Contains(rx.STOREID))
    .SelectTo<Classes.DataResponse>()
    .ToList();
```

*Query syntax*

```
var res =
    (from rx in con.DataRepoes
     where iaccess.Contains(rx.STOREID)
     select rx)
    .SelectTo<Classes.DataResponse>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you.  Yes, I prefer not using third party lib as it has to go through security review.  I will give this a try.

Comment: Thanks Ivan.  Worked like a lullaby to a crying baby.  It would be awesome for the next foolio (like me) if you can go through your code and show us how to fish.  I understand it all the way up until ` on rm.Name equals sm.Name` line.

Comment: Lol, it's a LINQ way to map source property/field to target property/field by name - see [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx). Glad that helped, happy coding :)

Comment: nice. One issue I see with this code when compared to what AutoMapper does is that you are having to perform the Reflection and Mapping at runtime, every time the method is called, which cage get pretty expensive. AutoMapper builds the map once upfront and cache it for the lifetime of your AppDomain. You probably want to do something similar here to avoid doing the reflection work all the time.

Comment: I think this is negligible compared to what happens when you execute the database query :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Automapper [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) for that.

Assuming the fields in `Classes.DataResponse` have the same names as the ones in `DataRepoes` you can then, do:

```
// During your application bootstrap, configure AutoMapper to create a map between the two types
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DataRepoes, Classes.DataResponse);


// Then you can ask AutoMapper to project the IQueryable directly to your DTO
List<Classes.DataResponse> res = con.DataRepoes
                                    .Where(rx => iaccess.Contains(rx.STOREID))
                                    .ProjectTo<Classes.DataResponse>()
                                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using LINQ.
However you can use "[AutoMapper](https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2/Pages/2)" to acheive this.
Just CreateMap for these two class and then Map them

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DataResponse,DataRepo>();//Assuming DataRepoes is collection of DataRepo types
List<Classes.DataResponse> res = (from rx in con.DataRepoes
                                  where iaccess.Contains(rx.STOREID)
                                  select Mapper.Map<Classes.DataResponse>(rx)).
                                  ToList<Classes.DataResponse>();
```

Hope that helps!!