# Base type query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a base class inherited by another class:

```
class Base { }
class Derived : Base { }
```

Entity Framework stores only instances of derived class. I want to select only columns, corresponding to the fields in base class and return them as `IEnumerable<Base>`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Why not just query Derived and then cast the results to Base?

Comment: @stuartd: Thank you for a quick reply. Surely, Cast<> was the first thing I've tried. As a result, I received this error: "Unable to cast the type 'Derived' to type 'Base'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types." It is only natural, since 'Base' is never stored in EF, Only 'Derived' is stored.

Comment: No, there isn't an easy way to select only Base columns. But you can take @stuartd advice. No `Cast` is needed, just `.AsEnumerable<Base>()` at the end of the query.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: Thank you very much for the idea. This was the second thing I've tried before asking this question. In fact, it worked without any problems but .AsEnumerable<Base>() in fact, returned an IEnumerable<Derived> as an output. At this point, I felt a bit as an idiot and decided to ask a community:)

Comment: Np:) I'm not quite sure what are you after. The above would really contain `Derived` objects with all data populated, but will look like `IEnumerable<Base>` thanks to the covariance. If you want a real `Base` objects, it's doable, but not easy (or better say, hard).

Comment: For now, I've tried two ways:
1. Select() manually in lambda all fields of 'Base' and then construct 'Base' in place with these selections adding it then to a new result list.
2. Iterate original query. Serialize every 'Derived' as JSON. Deserialize it as 'Base'. Add to result list.
Both ways work as expected but look so ugly that I still hope to discover some more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as soon as `Base` type is not recognized as **entity** by EF (because for some reason it does not allow projecting to entity types), you can use the following simple helper from my answer to [c# How can I create a collection of custom objects without going through each field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511479/c-sharp-how-can-i-create-a-collection-of-custom-objects-without-going-through-ea/38513149#38513149):

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TResult> SelectTo<TResult>(this IQueryable source)
    {
        var sourceType = source.ElementType;
        var resultType = typeof(TResult);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "x");
        var bindings =
            from rm in resultType.GetProperties().Concat<MemberInfo>(resultType.GetFields())
            join sm in sourceType.GetProperties().Concat<MemberInfo>(sourceType.GetFields())
                on rm.Name equals sm.Name
            select Expression.Bind(rm, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, sm));
        var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(resultType), bindings);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Select", new[] { sourceType, resultType },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(body, parameter))));
    }
}
```

like this:

```
IQueryable<Derived> yourQuery = ...;
return yourQuery.SelectTo<Base>();
```